# Significance of classes over data-structures

Tags: c++

Whats the significance of classes over data-structures or data-structures over classes?

Ok so The most basic ones can be that we can use "Access Specifiers In Classes" meaning we can prevent some and allow some to access our data.
next can be that data-hiding.

But whats the main thing that separates classes and data-structures? I mean why need data-structures when we have classes or vice-versa?

Comment: Just a guess, data structures are probably a left over from C. That's just my guess, though.

Comment: Was this a homework question? If you're asking the difference between `class` and `struct`, there isn't much of one, and I'm sure that's already been asked on SO. If you're asking for the conceptual difference, then this is more of an OOP design question and not related to C++.

Comment: I don't understand the question here. The two aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: yea this is a homework question. the instructor asked us to point the individual significance of one over the other. at least 10-15.

Comment: A data structure is what stores the data.  To make it useful you also need an API so that people can modify or query the data structure.  In C this is done with free functions.  In C++ you can do it the same way or you can build both the data structure and its API into a class.  The advantage is that the data in the structure can't be used at all without the API the class contains (the data hiding you mentioned).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo And not related to SO itself either if I am not mistaken.

Comment: The basic functionally between the two is identical in C++, the differences being default member access. With a struct, the member access is *public* by default, while with a class, access is *private*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of syntax, in C++ the only difference between a `class` and a `struct` is that members of a `struct` are public by default, while the members of a `class` are private by default.

From a perspective of *implied design intent*, however, there is a larger difference.  `struct` was/is a feature of C, and was/is used (in both C and C++) to help the programmer organize Plain Old Data in useful ways.  (for example, if you know every `Person` in your persons-database needs to store the person's first name, last name, and age, then you can put two `char` arrays and and `int` together in a `struct Person` and thereby make it more convenient to track all of that data as a unit, than if you had to store each of those fields separately).

C++ continues to provide that C-style struct functionality, but then goes further by adding additional features to better support object-oriented-programming.  In particular, C++ adds explicit support for *encapsulation* (via the `private` and `protected` keywords), functionality-extension via *inheritance*, the explicit tying-together of code and data via *methods*, and run-time polymorphism via *virtual methods*.  Note that all of these features can be approximated in C by manually following certain coding conventions, but by explicitly supporting them as part of the language, C++ makes them easier to use correctly and consistently.

Having done that, C++ then goes on to muddy the waters a bit, by making all of that new functionality available to `structs` as well as `classes`.  (This is why the technical difference is so minor, as described in the first paragraph)  However, I believe it is the case that when most programmers see a `struct` defined, they tend to have an implicit expectation that the struct is intended be used as a simple C-style data-storage/data-organization receptacle, whereas when they see a `class`, they expect it to include not just "some raw data" but also some associated business-logic, as implemented in the class's methods, and that the class will enforce its particular rules/invariants by requiring the calling code to call those methods, rather than allowing the calling code to read/write the class's member-variables directly.  (That's why public member-variables are discouraged in a `class`, but less so in a `struct` -- because a public member-variable in a class-object contradicts this expectation, and violates the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)).

Answer (score 2):

C++ has fundamantal types, and classes.

Struct and Class are both keywords that introduce a new class.  There are slightly different defaults.

Data structures are an arrangement of data with some kind of invarient.  They can be a class, they can contain classes, or they could be completely class free.

They are different categories of thing.  It is like asking what the difference is between steel and an automobile.

In a course assignment, what the teacher is asking for is for you to know the definition **the teacher** or **the text** taught those terms meant.  Terms mean what the context they are in tells them to mean.  It is a matter of "are you paying attention" not "do you know this fact"; having asked it of the internet, you have already failed.

Comment: haha..harsh. maybe you are correct but i didn't put it up here just to know the answer but to get some in-depth knowledge about if there is something that only class-specific or structure-specific that i didn't know about. and yes your answer was helpful so thanks:)